# Remove multiple viruses on Samsung A50

Tags: malware, antivirus, virus

On my Samsung A50, it detects:

- Android/Generic.S.7F619A!tr
- Android/Generic.S.6C6770!tr
- Android/Faketoken.SNT!tr
- Trojan.Dropper.AndroidOS.Hqwar.bb
- Android Generic.S.11954!tr

No antivirus or anti-malware can remove them.

How to remove them?

Comment: factory reset your device

Comment: I have factory reset it 3 times. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: if factory reset will not solve it, either means you have restored malicious apps from backup 3 times, or firmware itself is infected. latter one is very unlikely. you can however download and install latest ROM/firmware from PC

Comment: https://androidmtk.com/flash-samsung-stock-rom-using-odin

Comment: https://www.thecustomdroid.com/sideload-ota-update-stock-recovery-adb

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy